# Understanding Assimp's camera output

Tags: opengl, 3d, assimp

I'm writing a program to display 3d scene using Assimp3.0.

My work flow is:

1. Blender2.71 export fbx.
2. Assimp read fbx file.

The camera attribute from `aiCamera` is strange.

---

I have a camera in blender with:

(blender's coordinate)

location : `(0, -5, 0)`

rotation : `(90, 0, 0)`

This should be a simple front view camera.

---

Since Assimp will rotate all models `-90` degree along x-axis
I suppose Assimp will change this camera to

(OpenGL's coordinate (x : right) (y : up) (z : out of screen))

postion : `(0, -5, 0)`

up      : `(0, 0, 1)`

lookAt  : `(0, 1, 0)`

---

But in the `aiCamera` struct I got:

mPosition : `(5, 0, 0)`

mUp       : `(0, 1, 0)`

mLookAt   : `(0, 0, 1)`

---

What's the correct way to use `aiCamera`?

Answer (score 2):

An aiCamera lives in the aiNode graph. To quote the documentation for aiCamera and aiNode

> **aiCamera:** Cameras have a representation in the node graph [...]. This means, any values such as the look-at vector are not absolute, they're relative to the coordinate system defined by the node which corresponds to the camera.
>
> **aiNode:** Cameras and lights are assigned to a specific node name - if there are multiple nodes with this name, they're assigned to each of them.

So somewhere in your node graph there is a node with the same name as your  camera. This note contains the homogeneous transformation matrix corresponding to your camera's coordinate system. The product T*v will translate a homogeneous vector v from the camera coordinate system to the world coordinate system. (Denoting the root coordinate system as the world system and assuming the parent of the camera is the root).

The *mPosition*, *mUp*, and *mLookAt* are given in coordinates of the camera coordinate system, so they must be transformed to the world coordinate system. It is important to differentiate between mPosition which is a point in space, and the mUp and mLookAt which are direction vectors. The transformation matrix is composed of a rotation matrix R and a translation vector t.

```
       R   |  t
T = --------------
     0 0 0 |  1
```

mPosition in world coordinates is calculated as `mPositionWorld = T*mPosition`, while the direction vectors are calculated as `mLookAtWorld = R*mLookAt` and `mUpWorld = R*mUp`

In c++ the transformation matrix can be found by the following (assume the *aiScene* 'scene' has been loaded):

```
//find the camera's mLookAt
aiCamera** cameraList = scene->mCameras;
aiCamera* camera = cameraList[0] //Using the first camera as an    example
mVector3D camera->mLookAt;

//find the transformation matrix corresponding to the camera node
aiNode* rootNode = scene->mRootNode;
aiNode* cameraNode = rootNode->FindNode(camera->mName);
aiMatrix4x4 cameraTransformationMatrix = cameraNode->mTransformation;
```

The rest of the calculations can then be done using Assimp's linear algebra functions.